# Importing numpy on network drive in ipython fails

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

Today I got a weird error. I tried to import numpy in ipython on a network drive under windows 7 and it failed with the following error.

```
In [1]: import numpy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Z:\<ipython-input-1-5a0bd626bb1d> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pyc in <module>()
    141         return loader(*packages, **options)
    142
--> 143     import add_newdocs
    144     __all__ = ['add_newdocs']
    145

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py in <module>()
      7 #       core/fromnumeric.py, core/defmatrix.py up-to-date.

      8
----> 9 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     10
     11 ########################################################################
#######


C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py in <module>()
     11
     12 import scimath as emath
---> 13 from polynomial import *
     14 #import convertcode

     15 from utils import *

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py in <module>()
     15 from numpy.lib.function_base import trim_zeros, sort_complex
     16 from numpy.lib.type_check import iscomplex, real, imag
---> 17 from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
     18
     19 class RankWarning(UserWarning):

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py in <module>()
     46 from info import __doc__
     47
---> 48 from linalg import *
     49
     50 from numpy.testing import Tester

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in <module>()
     21         isfinite, size, finfo, absolute, log, exp
     22 from numpy.lib import triu
---> 23 from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
     24 from numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix import matrix_power
     25 from numpy.compat import asbytes

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified path is invalid.
```

Using the original python shell works as well as using ipython on C:\ drive. I tried to reinstall ipython and tried different versions but the error remains. I have no clue what's the cause of this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problems with numpy and linalg.  I fixed it by uninstalling numpy

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

then reinstalling.

```
pip install numpy
```

I didn't do this from the shared drive, I did it from my local drive.